# How to prevent the evaluation of arguments of clojure function?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn fun
  [& args]
  (println args))
(fun (+ 1 1) (+ 1 1))
```

I want the output of `fun` to be `((+ 1 1) (+ 1 1))`. I know quoting a form can make it unevaluated. But when I quote `args` as below,

```
(defn fun
  [& args]
  (println 'args))
```

the output is `args`, though. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure, like all non-lazy languages (which are almost all), evaluates arguments to a function call before calling the function.  When you call:

```
(foo (+ 1 1) (+ 1 1))
```

first the arguments are evaluated

```
(foo 2 2)
```

then the function is called, so in your `foo`, `args` is `(2 2)`.  There is no connection to the forms that produced those values.

If you want to prevent evaluation, you need to quote *before* evaluation, i. e. in your calling form:

```
(defn foo [& args]
  (println args))

(foo '(+ 1 1) '(+ 1 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick that is sometimes handy when there is more than one arg that needs quoting is to wrap everything in a vector, so as to avoid quoting each arg separately.  Consider:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(defn foo
  [args]  ; not rest args. no `&` present!
  (spyx args))

(dotest
  (foo (quote [(+ 1 2) (+ 3 4)])) ; sometimes this is easier to read & manipulate
  (foo '[(+ 1 2) (+ 3 4)]) ; this is a reader shortcut for the above
  (let [x 4]
    (foo `[(+ 1 2) (+ 3 ~x)]) ; backquote is handy, and always fully-qualifies Var names
  ))
```

with result

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
args => [(+ 1 2) (+ 3 4)]
args => [(+ 1 2) (+ 3 4)]
args => [(clojure.core/+ 1 2) (clojure.core/+ 3 4)]
```

We see we only need to quote the wrapping vector, not each item inside it.  This also shows that the single-quote is a reader shortcut for the `(quote ...)` special form.

The last example shows that we may use the syntax-quote (i.e. backquote).  It allows us to insert values into a template as with `x` here.  Since it is designed for macros, it adds the namespace to all Var references (i.e. the `+` function here).